# Best way when using prepared statement in nested loop

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

When executing multiple queries in nested loops what is the best way? I have a code like follows:

```
String sql1 = SQLContainer.SOME_SQL;
String sql2 = SQLContainer.SOME_SQL2;
    if (someThings != null) {
        for (Some some : someThings) {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ps.setString(1, some.name);
            ps.setString(2, some.type);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            if (some.getParams != null) {
                for (Some2 some2 : some.params) {
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
                    ps.setString(1, some2.name);
                    ps.setString(2, some2.value);
                    ps.setString(3, some2.type);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Is it ok to use like that?
2. Should I make 2 diferent loop, one for sql1 and one for sql2?
3. Should I create 2 different methods for different loops?
4. Or what should i do?

The sqls are just insert statements and two sqls are somehow related with each other. I dont want to insert somes when i get error from some.params too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL in a loop will have bad performance unless you do it right.

In your case, I'd strongly suggest to use **batched SQL**.

This would look like this for your first loop:

```
    int p1Count = 0;
    int BATCHSIZE = 1000;
    if (something) {
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(SQLContainer.SOME_SQL);        
            for (Some some : someThing) {
                ps1.setString(1, some.name);
                ps1.setString(2, some.type);
                ps1.addBatch();
                if(++p1Count % BATCHSIZE == 0) {
                    ps1.executeBatch();
                }
                ... 
            }
            ps1.executeBatch();
```

Just the same, you should split up your loops to do *one kind of SQL* at a time - so first do all the updates for *some* then (in second loop) do all the updates for *some2*

As long as you keep this within one transaction, you're fine.

You *could* probably keep the nested code as well - but your counters for s1 and s2 would be independent, so you really should not do that with autocommit on as there'd be no way of telling which items have been processed and which not.

In that case you'd end up with something like

```
        int p1Count = 0;
        int p2Count = 0;
        int BATCHSIZE = 1000;
        if (something) {
            try(PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(SQLContainer.SOME_SQL);
                   PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(SQLContainer.SOME_SQL2)) {                      
              for (Some some : someThing) {
                ps1.setString(1, some.name);
                ps1.setString(2, some.type);
                ps1.addBatch();
                if(++p1Count % BATCHSIZE == 0) {
                    ps1.executeBatch();
                }
                if (somethingElse) {
                    for (Some2 some2 : some.param) {
                        ps2.setString(1, some2.name);
                        ps2.setString(2, some2.value);
                        ps2.setString(3, some2.type);
                        ps2.addBatch();
                        if(++p2Count % BATCHSIZE == 0) {
                            ps2.executeBatch();
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
              p2.executeBatch();
              p1.executeBatch();
            } //End try-with-resource
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a private function and pass the parameters i.e. sql1, some.name, some.type

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
ps.setString(1, some.name);
ps.setString(2, some.type);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Based on the condition call the same function with different parameters.

Comment: Sqls and parameters are different. I updated code and question. Yes I can make different methods but why it would be better?